# How to recode factor levels from a vector in tidyverse?

Tags: r, tidyverse, levels, recode

Consider the data set below, there is a factor `No` with 34 levels, I want to recode these levels according to `newLvl`

**MWE**

```
structure(list(No = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 
34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "10", "13", "14", "15", "16", "18", "19", "21", 
"22", "23", "24", "25", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "34", "38", 
"39", "40", "42", "47", "48", "49", "53"), class = "factor"), 
    Gender = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Female", 
    "Male"), class = "factor"), Age = c(23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 
    39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 24, 
    24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 23, 23, 
    23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 23, 23, 23, 
    23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
    30, 30, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 
    25, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 
    22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 21, 21, 21, 
    21, 21, 21, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 
    24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 27, 27, 27, 
    27, 27, 27, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
    21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 
    23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 21, 21, 21, 21, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 
    34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 28, 
    28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 26, 26, 26, 26, 
    26, 26)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-218L))
```

**Vectors**

```
oldLvl <- c(23, 24, 48, 47, 3, 15, 49, 16, 21, 42, 39, 29, 28, 8, 38, 7, 53, 2, 19, 10, 5, 22, 6, 18, 14, 31, 27, 34, 25, 13, 40, 30, 4, 1)
newLvl <- c(1:34)
```

**Trial 1**

```
dplyr::mutate(Nbr  =  forcats::fct_recode(Nbr, 23 = "1", 24 = "2", 48 = "3", 47 = "4", 3 = "5", 15 = "6", 49 = "7", 16 = "8", 21 = "9", 42 = "10", 39 = "11", 29 = "12", 28 = "13", 8 = "14", 38 = "15", 7 = "16", 2 = "17", 53 = "18", 19 = "19", 10 = "20", 5 = "21", 22 = "22", 6 = "23", 18 = "24", 14 = "25", 31 = "26", 27 = "27", 34 = "28", 25 = "29", 13 = "30", 40 = "31", 30 = "32", 4 = "33", 1 = "34"))
```

**Trial 2**

```
      df1 <- df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Nbr = No) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Nbr  =  forcats::fct_recode(Nbr, "23" = "1", "24" = "2", "48" = "3", "47" = "4", "3" = "5", "15" = "6", "49" = "7", "16" = "8", "21" = "9", "42" = "10", "39" = "11", "29" = "12", "28" = "13", "8" = "14", "38" = "15", "7" = "16", "2" = "17", "53" = "18", "19" = "19", "10" = "20", "5" = "21", "22" = "22", "6" = "23", "18" = "24", "14" = "25", "31" = "26", "27" = "27", "34" = "28", "25" = "29", "13" = "30", "40" = "31", "30" = "32", "4" = "33", "1" = "34"))
```

**Question**

The two trials as above didn't work. How to recode the old levels with the new ones using `fct_*` family into a new variable say `Nbr`?

Comment: I would like to preserve 'No' in my data set and add 'Nbr' column which has the new recoded levels.

Comment: so a subject with `No` 23 would have `Nbr` equal to 1, and so on.

Comment: Your seecond trial should be `forcats::fct_recode(No, "23" = "1", ..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `!!!` after creating a named `vector` or `list`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
      mutate(Nbr = forcats::fct_recode(No,
            !!! setNames(as.character(oldLvl), newLvl)))
# A tibble: 218 x 4
#   No    Gender   Age Nbr  
#   <fct> <fct>  <dbl> <fct>
# 1 1     Male      23 34   
# 2 1     Male      23 34   
# 3 1     Male      23 34   
# 4 1     Male      23 34   
# 5 1     Male      23 34   
# 6 1     Male      23 34   
# 7 2     Male      39 18   
# 8 2     Male      39 18   
# 9 2     Male      39 18   
#10 2     Male      39 18   
# … with 208 more rows
```

Comment: do you also get a warning message `Unknown levels in `f`: 9, 11, 12, 17, 20, 26, 32, 33`, any idea why?

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, if I would abide with the syntax of the `fct_recode` function I could've done it in the way below. Key is `fct_recode (.f, "new" = "old")` not the other way around as in my 2nd unsuccessful trial in the post.

```
df1 <- df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Nbr  =  forcats::fct_recode(No, "1" = "23",
                                            "2" = "24",
                                            "3" = "48",
                                            "4" = "47",
                                            "5" = "3",
                                            "6" = "15",
                                            "7" = "49",
                                            "8" = "16",
                                            "9" = "21",
                                            "10" = "42",
                                            "11" = "39",
                                            "12" = "29",
                                            "13" = "28",
                                            "14" = "8",
                                            "15" = "38",
                                            "16" = "7",
                                            "17" = "2",
                                            "18" = "53",
                                            "19" = "19", # switching is not needed
                                            "20" = "10",
                                            "21" = "5",
                                            "22" = "22", # switching is not needed
                                            "23" = "6",
                                            "24" = "18",
                                            "25" = "14",
                                            "26" = "31",
                                            "27" = "27", # switching is not needed
                                            "28" = "34",
                                            "29" = "25",
                                            "30" = "13",
                                            "31" = "40",
                                            "32" = "30",
                                            "33" = "4",
                                            "34" = "1"))


# A tibble: 218 x 4
#   No    Gender   Age Nbr  
#   <fct> <fct>  <dbl> <fct>
# 1 1     Male      23 34   
# 2 1     Male      23 34   
# 3 1     Male      23 34   
# 4 1     Male      23 34   
# 5 1     Male      23 34   
# 6 1     Male      23 34   
# 7 2     Male      39 17   
# 8 2     Male      39 17   
# 9 2     Male      39 17   
# 10 2     Male      39 17   
# … with 208 more rows
```

Interestingly, no warnings were issued in this case.

Comment: You don't seem to answer the question, since you didn't provide vectors of names